# Whats wrong with my connection statement/Insert Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I can get it to work from home which I coded using mysqli but my school doesn't have that enabled so now it wont execute the query what am I doing wrong or is there a better way of doing this?

**!!!Update!!!**

So I connected to my website at home the one that works and redid the connection by just removing the i form the connections and the extra field (database name) in $dbc and it started getting errors. this happened even before I removed the database name from the connection. So I realized that the script doesn't know what database I'm connecting to. How can I fix this?

**Home (works)**

```
    /* database connection */

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', '9890667', 'zombies')
or die('Error Connecting to the MySQL Server');

/* insert query */

$query = "INSERT INTO zombie_sighted (first_name,last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, how_many, zombie_description, what_they_were_doing, fang_spotted, other, email) " .
"VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$when_it_happened','$how_long','$how_many','$zombie_description','$what_they_did','$fang_spotted','$other','$email')";

/* execute query */

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error querying database.');

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

**School(connects but query doesn't work now)** Updated

```
$dbc = mysql_connect('shcool url', 'username, 'password')
or die('Error Connecting to the MySQL Server');

/* insert query */

$query = "INSERT INTO zombie_sighted (first_name,last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, how_many, zombie_description, what_they_were_doing, fang_spotted, other, email) " .
"VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$when_it_happened','$how_long','$how_many','$zombie_description','$what_they_did','$fang_spotted','$other','$email')";

/* execute query */

$result = mysql_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error querying database.');

mysql_close($dbc);
```

Comment: can you connect to mysql using command line?

Comment: I can using putty i even imported the database script using the commandline.

Comment: You won't know what happened if all you see is "Error querying database." You need to call `mysqli_error()` somewhere...

Comment: i did that but it comes up blank the version I used is or die('Error querying database.' . mysql_error());

Comment: define "doesnt work". What do you see on the screen?

Comment: Usually at home I would see the fields that were filled in the form, now I get a blank page and an error that says "Error querying database.." Here's the url http://hydra.sullivan.edu/mquiles/site/

Comment: calling `mysqli_close()` on a database handle created with `mysql_connect()` (Note the lack of an 'i') will not work. The handles created by the two libraries are not interchangeable.

Comment: thank you Marc I missed that when editing

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain localhost is the correct MySQL path at your school location? If this is a shared server that doesn't allow things like shell access I bet the db path is not localhost as it would be on a dedicated box.

Comment: I changed that to post here the full url is being used in the real script. but it wont work regardless of which i use

Comment: Ahh ok just thought it might be something obvious. so you say your school enviro doesn't have the mysqli php extension installed, correct? Your mysql_connect statement looks fine, i would say you can do the or die statement instead of the if conditional

Comment: So this shouldn't really matter but try using hard ticks ' instead of the soft ticks " in the mysql_connect arguments

Comment: @ a.stgeorge the connection is being made now since now the error is "Error querying database."

Comment: @MichaelQuiles change your mysql_query statement

Comment: There is no need to pass the $dbc to the query method. instead follow the method you did before by selecting the database first then just running the query mysql_query($query);

Answer (score 0):

`$result = mysql_query($query)` try this.

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

you pass the resource in as first param when the query string is supposed to be.  also, make sure your `mysql_connection` fields are correct.

Comment: OK quick question if it works using mysqli can I just drop the i and leave it as mysql or do i have to rewrite it specifically for mysql?

Comment: they are two different extensions.

Comment: also drop the i on mysqli_close() as well.